# Move a node to finger using Swift + SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

**UPDATE:** I have solved the problem, and figured out a more simplified way to do this then the answer provided. My solution was to make the velocity of the SPACESHIP equal the distance it was from my finger touch. For faster movement, you can multiply this velocity by a constant. In this case, I used 16. I also got rid of setting lastTouch to nil in the touchesEnd event. That way, the ship will still stop even when I release my finger.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if let touch = lastTouch {
        myShip.physicsBody.velocity = CGVector(dx: (lastTouch!.x - myShip.position.x) * 16, dy: 0)
    }

}
```

===============================

I have a SPACESHIP node with movement restricted to the X-Axis. When the user PRESSES and HOLDS somewhere on the screen, I want the SPACESHIP to be able to move to the finger's x-coordinate, and not stop moving toward the finger until the finger is RELEASED. If the SPACESHIP is close to the users finger and the users finger is still pressed down, I want it to gradually slow down and stop. I also want this smooth motion to be applied when the SPACESHIP changes direction, starts, and stops.

I am trying to figure out the best way to do this.

So far, I have created the node and it moves correctly, but there is a problem: If I press on the screen and hold down, the ship will eventually cross over my finger and keep moving. This is because the logic to change direction of the ship is only triggered if I move my finger. So essentially, moving my finger over the ship to change the ships' direction works, but if the ship crosses over my still finger, it does't change direction

I need the SPACESHIP node to recognize when it has crossed over my still finger, and either change its direction or stop based on how close it is to my finger.

**Here is the relevant code:**

**Part 1:** When the user presses down, find out where the touch is coming from and move myShip (SPACESHIP) accordingly using velocity

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    if (touchLocation.x < myShip.position.x) {
        myShip.xVelocity = -200
    } else {
        myShip.xVelocity = 200
    }
}
```

**Part 2** When the user moves their finger, trigger an event that checks to see if the finger has now moved to the other side of the ship. If so, change direction of the ship.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    //distanceToShip value will eventually be used to figure out when to stop the ship
    let xDist: CGFloat = (touchLocation.x - myShip.position.x)
    let yDist: CGFloat = (touchLocation.y - myShip.position.y)
    let distanceToShip: CGFloat = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist))

    if (myShip.position.x < touchLocation.x) && (shipLeft == false) {
        shipLeft = true
        myShip.xVelocity = 200
    }

    if (myShip.position.x > touchLocation.x) && (shipLeft == true) {
        shipLeft = false
        myShip.xVelocity = -200
    }

}
```

**Part 3** When the user releases their finger from the screen, I want the ship to stop moving.

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    myShip.xVelocity = 0
}
```

**Part 4** Update event that changes the Ship's position

```
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
    let rate: CGFloat = 0.5; //Controls rate of motion. 1.0 instantaneous, 0.0 none.
    let relativeVelocity: CGVector = CGVector(dx:myShip.xVelocity - myShip.physicsBody.velocity.dx, dy:0);
    myShip.physicsBody.velocity = CGVector(dx:myShip.physicsBody.velocity.dx + relativeVelocity.dx*rate, dy:0);
```

Thanks for reading, and looking forward to a response!

Comment: Just for anyone googling here I put in a correct/modern answer for this old question, hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save yourself a lot of trouble by using: `myShip.physicsBody.applyImpluse(vector)`. It works by acting as if you gave `myShip` a push in the direction `vector` points. If you calculate `vector` as the x distance from your last touch location to `myShip`, then it'll accelerate, decelerate, change direction, etc. pretty close to the way you're describing because it'll be giving it little pushes in the right direction on each `update`.

Basically you store the last touch location then, in your `update` function, you calculate the `CGVector` pointing from `myShip` to `lastTouch` and apply that as an impulse to your physics body.

Something like:

```
var lastTouch: CGPoint? = nil

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    lastTouch = touchLocation
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    lastTouch = touchLocation
}

// Be sure to clear lastTouch when touches end so that the impulses stop being applies
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    lastTouch = nil
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    // Only add an impulse if there's a lastTouch stored
    if let touch = lastTouch {
        let impulseVector = CGVector(touch.x - myShip.position.x, 0)
        // If myShip starts moving too fast or too slow, you can multiply impulseVector by a constant or clamp its range
        myShip.physicsBody.applyImpluse(impulseVector)
    }
}
```

You'll also probably want to play with the `linearDamping` and `angularDamping` values on `myShip.physicsBody`. They'll help determine how fast `myShip` accelerates and decelerates.

I maxed out the values at `1.0` in my app:

```
myShip.physicsBody.linearDamping = 1.0
myShip.physicsBody.angularDamping = 1.0
```

If `myShip` doesn't stop fast enough for you, you can also try applying some breaking in your `update` function:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    // Only add an impulse if there's a lastTouch stored
    if let touch = lastTouch {
        let impulseVector = CGVector(touch.x - myShip.position.x, 0)
        // If myShip starts moving too fast or too slow, you can multiply impulseVector by a constant or clamp its range
        myShip.physicsBody.applyImpluse(impulseVector)
    } else if !myShip.physicsBody.resting {
        // Adjust the -0.5 constant accordingly
        let impulseVector = CGVector(myShip.physicsBody.velocity.dx * -0.5, 0)
        myShip.physicsBody.applyImpulse(impulseVector)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, first of all, thank you so much for taking the time to give such a detailed response! You are fricken awesome! Changing lastTouch to nil at the end of a touch is a stroke of genius - this is also just a great example of the power of this new language.

I'm getting stuck on something. For some reason, I'm getting an error in the update function:

"let impulseVector: CGVector = CGVector(lastTouch.x - myShip.position.x, 0)" 

It says CGPoint does not have a member named X. What is going on?

Comment: You're welcome! The problem you're having with setting `impulseVector` is a typo on my part, sorry about that. It should be `touch` and not `lastTouch`. I edited my answer and fixed it.

Comment: Mike, thanks so much! I used touch instead of last touch and the program ran. This gives me a good starting point to tweak it more. A couple closing questions/thoughts. In the third example section, did you mean "myShip.physicsBody.applyImpulse(impulseVector)" instead of impulseDirection? Also, I'm confused about the "if let touch = lastTouch" statement. If you are defining touch in the if statement, isn't it's default value nil? So the if statement will only run if lastTouch and touch are nil. But then it doesn't make sense that you can use touch to assign an x-coordinate. Why is there one =?

Comment: Yep, that's supposed to be `impulseVector`, oops. That's fixed now. As for `if let touch = lastTouch` that's using a swift feature called [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_485). Basically it'll only evaluate to true if `lastTouch` is not `nil` and, in that case, it'll set `touch` to the non-`nil` value.

Comment: Okay thanks! I actually ended up using an equation that used velocity instead of impulse vector. The problem with impulseVector in this situation that multiplying the current vector by another every update caused the ship to go too fast. So I found an even simpler way to create the move motion using: "myShip.physicsBody.velocity = CGVector(dx: (lastTouch!.x - myShip.position.x) * 16, dy: 0)" and making sure lastTouch was never nil, that way the ship will stop even if my finger is off the screen. Thanks for helping me get to this destination!

Answer (score 2):

For 2017 here's the easy way to do what is explained in the correct answer here.

There's no need to store the previous position, **it is given to you**...

```
  override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let t: UITouch = touches.first! as UITouch

    let l =      t.location(in: parent!)
    let prev =   t.previousLocation(in: parent!)

    let delta = (l - prev).vector

    physicsBody!.applyImpulse(delta)
 }
```

That's it.

---

*Two notes.*  (A) properly you should divide the delta distance by the deltaTime to get the correct impulse. If you're a hobbyist really just multiply by "about 100" and you'll be fine. (B) note that of course you will need an extension or function to convert CGPoint to CGVector, it's impossible to do anything without that.

Answer (score -1):

In your `thuchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` store the touch location as the "target". In the `update` then check the position of your ship and reset the `xVelocity` to 0 if the ship has reached/passed the target.

Since you are only interested in the x coordinate you could also store just `touchLocation.x`. You can also reverse the velocity but I think that would look strange. Note that if the user moves the finger again, your ship will start moving again because the `touchMoved` will be triggered again.

On a side note, within `touchesMoved` you are also setting the `shipLeft` property but this is not set in your `touchesBegan`. If this property is used elsewhere you should sync its use.