# Swift + Sprite Kit: CGPoint does not have a member named "x" when using with CGVector

Tags: xcode, vector, swift, sprite-kit, cgpoint

Okay, I'm stumped on this one. For some reason, I can't use the x coordinate in a CGPoint value when trying to figure out a vector. Take a look at the sample playground code below:

```
var lastTouch: CGPoint? = nil
let myPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
let impulseVector: CGVector = CGVector(lastTouch.x - 20, 0) //returns error
```

The error message is specifically on the ".x" and says "CGPoint? does not have a member named "x" Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Here is a snippet of what I am trying to apply this to:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if let touch = lastTouch {
        let impulseVector: CGVector = CGVector(lastTouch.x - myShip.position.x, 0)
        myShip.physicsBody.applyImpulse(impulseVector)
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to use the "touch" constant that you just made, otherwise what is the point of setting it? So replace the error line with `let impulseVector: CGVector = CGVector(touch.x - myShip.position.x, 0)`

Comment: Hey Jack, good question. I don't think I showed enough code here to clearly show what's going on. Essentially, the purpose is to check if lastTouch is nil. This question is based on an answer to another question I had that I am having trouble implementing. Check out my reply to the top rated answer if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277956/move-a-node-to-finger-using-swift-spritekit

Comment: lastTouch is an optional, thats why it doesn't have a member named 'x'. touch on the other hand is unwrapped (due to the if let statement), so you should be able to access its x property.

Comment: Ok, i think i understand now. Try doing `lastTouch!.x` as this will unwrap the optional. As you are already checking to see if it exists, then this shouldn't cause any errors. Just as a side note, you could also do `if lastTouch != nil` but maybe this doesn't work as well with the rest of your code

Comment: Jack, that was it! I needed to force unwrap it. Thanks so much, you saved me a heartache an a half!

Comment: Not a problem. Sorry i didnt get back to you sooner. I know its annoying when it takes so long to get a reply.